# Connection Failed! Check output console

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, netbeans-7, osx-yosemite

To connect to mysql database using java on mac Yosemite and to the complete url of jdbcdriver jar file in CLASS PATH. The netbeans console gives that "java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)." I tried many ways as forums, but it still not works.

Here my codes

```
//STEP 1. Import required packages
import java.sql.*;

public class JDBCExample {
   // JDBC driver name and database URL
   static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
   static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/library";

   //  Database credentials
   static final String USER = "root";
   static final String PASS = "default$";

   public static void main(String[] args) {
   Connection conn = null;
   Statement stmt = null;
   ResultSet rs = null;
   try{
      //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver (automatically done since JDBC 4.0)
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

      //STEP 3: Open a connection
      System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

      //STEP 4: Execute a query
      System.out.println("Creating database...");
      stmt = conn.createStatement();
      rs = stmt.executeQuery("select uid uname from User");

      //STEP 5: Process the results
      while(rs.next()){
          System.out.println("User ID="+rs.getInt("uid")+", Name="+rs.getString("uname"));
      }

   }catch(SQLException se){
      //Handle errors for JDBC
      se.printStackTrace();
   }catch(Exception e){
      //Handle errors for Class.forName
      e.printStackTrace();
   }finally{
      //finally block used to close resources
      try{
         if(stmt!=null)
            stmt.close();
      }catch(SQLException se2){
      }// nothing we can do
      try{
         if(conn!=null)
            conn.close();
      }catch(SQLException se){
         se.printStackTrace();
      }//end finally try
   }//end try
   System.out.println("Goodbye!");
}//end main
}//end JDBCExample
```

Here are results:

```
Connection Failed! Check output console
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:959)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3870)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3806)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:871)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1686)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1207)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2254)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2285)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2084)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:795)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:400)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:327)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource.getConnection(MysqlDataSource.java:422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource.getConnection(MysqlDataSource.java:134)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource.getConnection(MysqlDataSource.java:105)
    at cs157a_test.DataSourceTester.main(DataSourceTester.java:54)
```

Comment: Are you sure, your db url port (default it's 3306), username and password is correct? Just making sure of it

Comment: AFAIK it will be other error in case of wrong port like "Connection refused"

@B-Y do you able to connect co mysql command line client with credentials specified in code? E.g. in terminal `mysql -u root -p` ?

Answer (score 0):

The exception you got is telling you that you have successfully connected to the server but, the user `root` is not allowed/granted to connect from `localhost`.

You have to review your mysql user privilege table and ensure you have a row allowing `root` to connect from `localhost` with a right password.

The following SQL will show this:

```
SELECT host, user FROM mysql.user;
```

If there is a row for `root` and `localhost` or `root` and `%` then you have to reset your password with this SQL:

```
set password for 'root'@'localhost' = password('your_password');
```

If there is no row, you have to create it and then set privileges on data bases you want to access with that user.

You can achieve this with the following SQL:

```
CREATE USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'your_password';
GRANT ALL ON YOU_DATABASES.* TO 'root'@'localhost';
```

Finally you have to flush privileges or restart mysql. Try again and sure you will get connected.

Comment: I showed what I did, but it does not work. What did I wrong?

Comment: @B-Y I hope your password string in code looks like this:
`static final String PASS = "829891";`

Comment: Did you restart mysql after changing password?

Comment: Yes. I try to restart it. it seems that could not restart instead to restart my computer

Comment: Can you show what returns this sentence `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'root'@'localhost';`?

Comment: I found new "ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file", please help me out

Comment: I can show "SHOW GRANTS FOR 'root'@'localhost';" as well.

Comment: My JDBC has the same error as "java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)."

Answer (score 0):

Would you like to check this out. It works for me.

```
    import java.*;
    import java.sql.*;
    import java.util.*;
    //STEP 1. Import required packages
    import java.sql.*;

    public class Memory {
     // JDBC driver name and database URL
     static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
     static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/library";

     //  Database credentials
     static final String USER = "root";
     static final String PASS = "root";

     public static void main(String[] args) {
     Connection conn = null;
     Statement stmt = null;
     ResultSet rs = null;

     try{
        //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver (automatically done since JDBC 4.0)
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        //STEP 3: Open a connection
        System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

        //STEP 4: Execute a query
        System.out.println("Creating database...");
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery("select uid, uname from uisend");

        //STEP 5: Process the results
        while(rs.next()){
            System.out.println("User ID="+rs.getInt("uid")+", Name="+rs.getString("uname"));
        }

     }catch(SQLException se){
        //Handle errors for JDBC
        se.printStackTrace();
     }catch(Exception e){
        //Handle errors for Class.forName
        e.printStackTrace();
     }finally{
        //finally block used to close resources
        try{
           if(stmt!=null)
              stmt.close();
        }catch(SQLException se2){
        }// nothing we can do
        try{
           if(conn!=null)
              conn.close();
        }catch(SQLException se){
           se.printStackTrace();
        }//end finally try
     }//end try
     System.out.println("Goodbye!");
    }//end main
    }//end JDBCExample
```

Comment: I changed your code on 2 of the lines. static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/library"; static final String PASS = "root"; If my answer is upvoted then others will know that this answer works and can benefit out of it like you.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why it works as my codes and do not need to change.

```
User ID=1001, Name=17
User ID=1002, Name=Kim
User ID=1003, Name=Jane Koffman
User ID=1004, Name=Katherine H. Lang
User ID=1005, Name=Smith
User ID=1006, Name=Juanita J. Palmer
User ID=1007, Name=Otherone with no age
User ID=1008, Name=Ethel W. Williams
User ID=1009, Name=Someone with no age
User ID=1010, Name=Candis C. Whitehead
User ID=1011, Name=Kim
User ID=1012, Name=Margaret F. Delmonte
User ID=1013, Name=Susan M. McKeel
User ID=1014, Name=Kim
User ID=1015, Name=Shirley A. Dehaven
User ID=1016, Name=Smith
User ID=1017, Name=Chad G. Turner
User ID=1018, Name=Suzanne J. Champine
User ID=1019, Name=Harry King
Goodbye!
```